# UINavigationController + UITabBarController + UISegmentedControl with TableView/MapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am doing some training about the handling of the flickr photos.. i want to display the most popular places and the related photos. At the moment, the application has a TabBarController, and each tab has a navigation controller as the "starting point". The storyboard is: [TableView of places] -> [Table View of photos] -> [Scroll View of the image]
Now, i would like to give the user the chance to switch to a map representation instead of the table view, without doing any further segue.

I think the best way to do this is to use a `UISegmentedControl`, so i used this layout  [[link to image]](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/614097/layout.png). When the table is visible, the map is hidden (and viceversa).

Using only the table representation, i used a TableViewController. With this modifications, I subclassed a UIViewController and I implemented "by hand" the two Table protocols (`delegate` and `datasource`), i linked the outlets, but now **the table scrolling has a low framerate**.

I ask flickr the most popular place, i split the JSON and I obtain an NSArray of NSDictionary s that i've called 'places' (each dictionary = place). Then i splitted those places in sections by country: the list of countries (alphabetically ordered) is called 'sortedCountries'. Then, i've created a NSDictionary called 'placesByCountry' (key=country / value=array of places for that country).

Here some code i wrote:

```
- (NSArray*)addressForPlace:(NSDictionary*)place {
    return [[place objectForKey:@"_content"] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]; }

- (NSString *)countryForSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.sortedCountries objectAtIndex:section]; }

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self countryForSection:section]; }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.placesByCountry count]; }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *country = [self countryForSection:section];

    NSArray *placesByCountry = [self.placesByCountry objectForKey:country];

    return [placesByCountry count]; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewLocal cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Top Place Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewLocal dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *country = [self countryForSection:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *placesByCountry = [self orderedPlacesForCountry:country];

    NSDictionary *place = [placesByCountry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *address = [self addressForPlace:place];
    cell.textLabel.text = [address objectAtIndex:0];

    NSMutableString *remainigAddres = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSString *s in address) {
        if ([address indexOfObject:s] != 0) {
            if ([address indexOfObject:s] != [address indexOfObject:[address lastObject]])
                [remainigAddres appendFormat:@"%@, ", s];
            else
                [remainigAddres appendString:s];
        }
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = remainigAddres;


    return cell; }
```

Is this the **right approach** for my problem ? What should i do to **improve performances** ? I have just checked the cell identifier, and the aren't images to download ! The only asyncronous queue happens on the initial population of the table (when i query flickr)..

EDIT:
maybe i found the problem... the table scrolling has low framerate especially when scrolling large sections.. as you can see, in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, i call another method, orderedPlacesForCountry:. This method performs a sorting on-the-fly:

```
- (NSArray*)orderedPlacesForCountry:(NSString*)country {
    NSArray* places = [self.placesByCountry objectForKey:country];
    if (DEBUG_LOG_ACTIVE) NSLog(@"places: %d", [places count]);

    NSMutableArray* cities = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary* place in places) {
        [cities addObject:[[self addressForPlace:place] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    if (DEBUG_LOG_ACTIVE) NSLog(@"cities: %d", [cities count]);

    NSArray *sortedCities = [cities sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    if (DEBUG_LOG_ACTIVE) NSLog(@"sorted cities: %d", [sortedCities count]);

    NSMutableArray *sortedPlaces = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[places count]];

    for (NSString* city in sortedCities) {
        //per ogni città cerco in places quel place
        for (NSDictionary* place in places) {
            if ([[[self addressForPlace:place] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:city])
                //e lo aggiungo a sorted
                [sortedPlaces addObject:place];
        }
    }

    if (DEBUG_LOG_ACTIVE) NSLog(@"sorted places: %d", [sortedPlaces count]);

    return sortedPlaces; }
```

If i do not sort the places of a country, the table scrolling is fine.. so i'll try to perform the sorting at the beginning, when the data gets loaded, and not "on-the-fly" while scrolling.

Comment: This sounds like the correct approach I am not sure why you are getting a low frame rate can you give us more detail on what you mean by this? I suspect if there is an issue with refreshing the tableview you will be doing something computationally heavy when the table is scrolling (possibly updating the hidden map?)

Comment: @ScottSherwood question updated ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the litte info you're giving to us, I asume that the piece of code that is making your table slow is your cells, are you showing some kind of images in the cell? if so, are you downloading them synchronously? are you inserting webviews or big textviews inside the cell?

This are the kind of things that can make a tableview to run slow, please add more info in order to help you!